# How to access JavaFX components in the constructor of Controller Class

Tags: java, javafx

I am loading an FXML file the following way

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("register.fxml"));
        Controller c = new Controller("Welcome to EAST");
        loader.setController(c);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        fx.setScene(scene); // fx is a JFXPanel which is used to integrate FX in Swing
```

The above code is working fine, now I want to access the the default values of `textFields` of the `register.fxml` in the constructor of Controller Class but It gives and error: **Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException**.

**Note:** I have assigned some default values to the textFields that is why I want to access them.

following is My Controller class

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField pass;
    @FXML
    private TextField ip;
    @FXML
    private TextField sPort;
    @FXML
    private TextField fPort;

    public Controller(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(ip.getText()); // this line gives the NullPointerException Error
    }

    @FXML
    private void login() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void register(){

    }

    @FXML
    private void cancel(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated . Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Before the controls can be injected by the FXMLLoader the controller instance must be created. You use a initialize method instead of the constructor in your controller.

Let your controller implement https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html .

Or implement

```
class MyController {

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        //Will be called by FXMLLoader
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FXMLLoader will start loading and initializing the FX Components in loader.load(). In that moment it needs already the controller for event handling. So if you create the Controller (constructor), the FXML can't be available.

Only in event methods called from the FXML you are able to access the GUI components. Or add a separate Method to the controller like

```
public void init() { ... }
```

called after loading... accessing the components.

Comment: The `initialize()` (not `init()`) method is called automatically be the FXMLLoader once it has created and injected all the `@FXML`-annotated fields.